# Can I pause the notifications in Reality Composer?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, reality-composer

In Reality Composer, I identified the notification called replay.

[image]

In Xcode, I controlled the notification by adding this code:

`Scene1.notifications.replay.post()`

Can I call the method for stopping or pausing this notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Reality Composer you can create as many notifications as you want. Thus you can create an empty notification that will not trigger the Behavior when it is posted. The example below shows how every `even click` does not trigger an animation.

---

[image]

```
boxScene.notifications.none.post()
```

[image]

### SwiftUI version

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State private var counter: Int = 0
    @State private var boxScene = try! Experience.loadBox()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ARViewContainer(boxScene: $boxScene).ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Tap me") {
                    counter += 1
                    
                    if (counter % 2) == 1 {
                        boxScene.notifications.theMask.post()
                    } else {
                        boxScene.notifications.none.post()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    @Binding var boxScene: Experience.Box
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxScene)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

### UIKit version

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let boxScene = try! Experience.loadBox()
    var counter = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxScene)
    }
    
    @IBAction func tapMe(_ sender: UIButton) {
        counter += 1
        
        if (counter % 2) == 1 {
            boxScene.notifications.theMask.post()
        } else {
            boxScene.notifications.none.post()
        }
    }
}
```